# Uwp app crash immediately after compiled with .net native toolchain

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-store-apps

I'm creating an uwp app. My app works well in debug mode. But when compiled with .net native toolchain, which is essential to publish app to the Store, it crash immediately. I was trying to enable all the exception settings but it didn't hit any breakpoints. All the information I can get from the output is:

> The program '[9548] DemoBuildError.exe' has exited with code
>   -1073741511 (0xc0000139) 'Entry Point Not Found'. Activation of the Windows Store app
>   '9e380736-23cf-476f-b625-be7baa70ad56_jatac5brr3jea!App' failed with
>   error 'The app didn't start'.

I also try to create new project and copy, paste carefully as mentioned in some previous threads but no luck.
Here is my demo project to reproduce the error: https://bitbucket.org/wpdev01/demobuilderror

Any ideas?

Comment: If you created a new project, it should definitely compile with .NET Native just fine. I would suggest slowly adding the code from your main project to see where exactly do the problems start.

Comment: I knew that .NET Native had problem with the library which I want to implement. In the main project, I even don't need to call to the library, the app still has the same problem.

Comment: I am unable to access the BitBucket link. Could you make it public? Or post it somewhere as a zip file?

Comment: @CK01 - Your libraries need to be portable into the UWP framework. If your're using a rogue DLL, that might be your problem.

Comment: The time I also encountered this issue (no problem in Debug, immediate crash in Release), it was because of the combination of using reflection and .NET Native compiling. See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/978 . With me, adding ```<Namespace Name="System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters" Dynamic="Required All"/>``` to the Properties/Default.rd.xml file solved the crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Since your repo is private, I'm also facing the same problem, I guess it's due to some third party controls your refered.

In my project, I unloaded all third party controls, it works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

in your case its quite a problem.

1. try to add "unhandledexception" :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=netframework-4.8
2. debug and see what's next.

   in debug mode compiler optimizations are turned off but the app is should work the same.